# Change the CreatedDate format in Apex

Tags: apex, datetime, formatting

I have the following apex code that displays the created date of records:

```
for(let i=0; i<emailMessages.length; i++){
replyBody += 'On '+ emailMessages[i].CreatedDate + ' ' + emailMessages[i].From_Name__c +' ' +'responded: ';
}
```

This above code displays the message like this:

> On 2022-06-30T15:27:36.000Z Sarah Kat responded:

I want to change the date format so it can be displayed as below:

> On Thu, Jun 30, 2022 at 4:26 PM Sarah Kat responded:

As there anyway where we can change the date format directly in apex?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look through the [Datetime class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) to see how to use the `format()` method (the one that takes a formatting string)

Comment: for(let i=0; i<emailMessages.length; i++){
replyBody += 'On '+ emailMessages[i].CreatedDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a') + ' ' + emailMessages[i].From_Name__c +' ' +'wrote: '+ '<br>' +  emailMessages[i].HTML_Body__c + '<br> <br>';
        }

Comment: I tried the above code but it didn't work